# How to connect a external volume to IBM Cloud Code Engine

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I have a docker image that access a database referenced by the -v parameter. Does someone have simple instructions to have it running in Cloud Code Engine and storing the database in an object storage?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly you are looking to attach a persistent volume to run a docker image that has a database included in it.
This isn't supported at the moment and I would suggest using one of the dedicated platform database services